# Word for a big/influential company daring to commit immoral thing

Tags: word-choice

Those companies do so because they think they have dominated the market
and the customers can not live without their service.

For example, big technology companies in China like Tencent and Baidu
can breach users' privacy by simply monitoring their text and voice communication and other sensitive data for not only commercial usage but also for helping Government spying the public like what's described in book 1984 with AI and Big Data.

Even now in Google, there has been a disclosure that Google's developing DragonFly Project for censored engine to re-enter Chinese market. 
I think one reason they dare to do so without fearing the consequence is that many people have formed reliance on them so that they can keep prying on user's privacy.

Comment: Hi Jeffson, welcome to EL&U. You might not have read the tag info for [tag:single-word-requests]: "To ensure your question is not closed as off-topic, please be specific about the intended use of the word. *You must include a sample sentence demonstrating how the word would be used*."  You can add this using the [edit] link. For further guidance, see [ask], and make sure you also take the EL&U **[Tour]** :-)

Comment: Are you sure you want just a single word? There are so many ways to describe what you are talking about that limiting to a single word would be a disservice.

Comment: Sorry I am new, maybe I can change into phrase request or word- choice?

Comment: Sadly, this is known as "normal".

Answer (score -1):

I would recommend 
***VIOLATOR*** .

It's a noun formed by affixation (to violate + or).

According to [Macmillan Dictionary](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/violate?q=Violator%20#violate__8) :

DERIVED WORD

***violator***

NOUN [COUNTABLE]

To ***violate*** -

To do something that is in opposition to a law, agreement,  principle etc.

// Companies that violate environmental laws will be heavily fined.

Though dictionaries usually refer the noun to a person ([Oxford](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/violator),  etc.) it can be used for companies as well.

Look at some examples from [Context.Reverso.Net](https://context.reverso.net/translation/):

It also underscores the need for the adoption of national legislations to sanction all ***violators***, including companies.

The Toyota Motor Company and some, but not all, of its regional distributors assisted the Panel in its efforts to identify possible ***violators*** of the embargo.

Singapore has the legal means to penalize ***violators*** and has taken enforcement action against several companies.

Comment: Many of your answers include a reference to "Reverso.context.net", which is the wrong url. It's actually [context.reverso.net](https://context.reverso.net/translation/). Somewhat ironic really ;-)